# Showing Detail Screen Keeps Crashing My App

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app keeps crashing when I'm selecting a cell and trying to show the detail screen for the selected item. Here is the code.

```
class ItemScreenManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isShowingDetailScreen = false
}

struct ItemScreen: View {
  @StateObject var manager = ItemScreenManager()
  @State var selectedItem: Item? = nil
  @State var isShowingDetailScreen = false

  let numberOfColumns = [
    GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1)
  ]
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: numberOfColumns, spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ItemCellView(item: item)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item
                            manager.isShowingDetailScreen = true
                        }
                }
            }
        }  
          .navigationBarTitle("Items")
          .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }

    .sheet(isPresented: $manager.isShowingDetailScreen) {
        ItemDetailScreen(item: selectedItem!)
    }
  }
}
```

So the above code works it doesn't crash my app. If I don't use the manager it crashes my app. So if I change the tap gesture & sheet modifiers to look something like.

```
.onTapGesture { 
  selectedItem = item
  isShowingDetailScreen = true
}

.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDetailScreen) {
  ItemDetailScreen(item: selectedItem!)
}
```

I would think this would be the same thing as using the manager but I'm kind of new to SwiftUI and don't know why this crashes my app. Just wanted to know why the selected Item is nil when I don't use the manager.

Comment: try this: `.sheet(item: $selectedItem) { itm in
            ItemDetailScreen(item: itm)
        }`

Comment: @workingdog Yeah that did the job, not crashing anymore. Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to know why that work and the other one didn't. :)

Comment: @LuisRamirez try to avoid `!` as this is an unsafe unwrap of the optional. Note that `selectedItem` is of type `Item?` - can be nil or Item. If it is nil at the time of execution the program will crash.